# How to use PriorityQueue in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I seem to have an issue with using `tf.PriorityQueue` in tensorflow. The documentation says that the shapes argument is not required for initialization. I cannot specify the shape of the tensor as it is dynamic and the shape is determined at runtime.

From the tensorflow documentation on [tf.PriorityQueue](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/PriorityQueue):

```
__init__(capacity,types,shapes=None,names=None,shared_name=None,name='priority_queue')
```

> Args:
>
> capacity: An integer. The upper bound on the number of elements that may be stored in this queue.
>
> types: A list of DType objects. The length of types must equal the number of 
>   tensors in each queue element, except the first priority element. The first tensor in each element is the priority, which must be type int64.
>
> shapes: (Optional.) A list of fully-defined TensorShape objects, with the same length as types, or None.
>
> names: (Optional.) A list of strings naming the components in the queue with the same length as dtypes, or None. If specified, the dequeue methods return a dictionary with the names as keys.
>
> shared_name: (Optional.) If non-empty, this queue will be shared under the given name across multiple sessions.
>
> name: Optional name for the queue operation.

However, the following code produces a TypeError:

```
def build_queue():
    with tf.name_scope("Queue"):
        q = tf.PriorityQueue(capacity=2,types=tf.uint8,name="iq",shared_name="queue")
    return q

File "C:\Users\devar\Documents\EngProj\SSPlayer\test\dist_cnn.py", line 212, in create_model
    infer_q = build_infer_queue()
  File "C:\Users\devar\Documents\EngProj\SSPlayer\test\dist_cnn.py", line 143, in build_queue
    shared_name="queue")
  File "C:\Users\devar\Envs\RL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 903, in __init__
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\devar\Envs\RL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 3409, in priority_queue_v2

TypeError: Expected list for 'shapes' argument to 'priority_queue_v2' Op, not None.
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that according to the comments in `priority_queue_v2` in `gen_data_flow_ops.py` it has to be present.

> Args:
>       shapes: A list of shapes (each a `tf.TensorShape` or list of `ints`).
>         The shape of each component in a value. The length of this attr must
>         be either 0 or the same as the length of component_types. If the length of
>         this attr is 0, the shapes of queue elements are not constrained, and
>         only one element may be dequeued at a time.

It accepts `shapes=[()]` or `shapes=[tf.TensorShape([])]` but without that I see the same error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import threading

list = tf.placeholder(tf.int64,name="x")


def build_queue():
    with tf.name_scope("Queue"):
        q = tf.PriorityQueue(2,tf.int64,shapes=[()],name="iq",shared_name="queue")
    return q

queue = build_queue()

enqueue_op = queue.enqueue_many([list,list])

dequeue_op = queue.dequeue()

data_batch = tf.train.batch([dequeue_op], batch_size=2, capacity=40)

init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.initialize_local_variables())

sess = tf.Session()

def put():
    sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={list: [1,2,3,4,5]})

mythread = threading.Thread(target=put, args=())
mythread.start()

tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)

try:
    while True:
        print (sess.run(data_batch))
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print ("Queue empty")


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run( build_queue() )
```